# Issue with hibernate 6 naming stategy with sqlite

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I create table named user as such

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name= "User")
@Table(name = "User")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String userName;

    public User() {
    }
```

but when i attempt to retrieve info from it with a controller

```
   @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/getUsers")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

i get
SQL Error: 1, SQLState: null
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: user)

checking the created database , i see the actual table name that was created  is HTE_user

i m using

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'
implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.1.6.Final'
```

any idea how to access the generated table correctly ?

Comment: hey ,
uploaded a demo of the issue to github : https://github.com/yaniv33/sqllite

Comment: Seems like the github i commited was not set to public 
it is now :  github.com/yaniv33/sqllite

Comment: I don't know much about SQLite, but `user` is usually a keyword in SQL, so try naming the table differently.

Comment: Thanks Christian , tried it but the HTE_ prefix would appear on all tables created.. 
Changing the prefix did not help either since the prefix would only come after the HTE_ prefix

Comment: The HTE tables are temporary tables which are pre-created for the purpose of multi-table updates/deletes. You can ignore these. hbm2ddl should emit other tables as well though.

Comment: but in the current setup i get "no such table: user" , i suspect it is due to the HTE_ prefix .. , how could i get a valid result to userRepository.findAll();

Answer (score 0):

Your database simply does not contain a table with that name. You have to create it or configure `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` for your application so that the schema is dropped/recreated automatically.